# Conversion date from tweet in python

Tags: python, datetime-conversion

I have some problem to convert date in `python`.

For example you can see on the `csv` file, at the index 0 for the column "created_date", I have the value `"1550740786000"`.

I would like the convert this date in a more "traditional form"

I tried to use the code below :

---

Input:

```
time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',time.localtime(int(pd_testData_filtered["created_at"].iloc[0])))
```

---

Output:

### 51109-10-14 02:13:20

This tweet has been published at 14:29 20/02/2019

Could someone help me?

Best regards.

[CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaGCZ.png)

Comment: Are you sure your time objects are correct? If you divide by 1000 it works a lot better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a Posix timestamp but expressed in milliseconds. So strip the last 3 digits:

```
>>> timestamp = 1550740786000
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp / 1000)
datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 21, 10, 19, 46)
```

This isn't exactly the publication time you report, but some hours earlier, and it is plausibly close enough to be worth investigating: the original timestamp of a retweet, maybe?

Comment: I suspect the couple hours difference is due to a timezone difference.

Comment: @Nathan Timezone differences are rarely more than 13 hours, and even ignoring the hour offset, that wouldn't explain the 10 minute difference.

Comment: It is basically a tweet from Theresa May. I am actually in Moscow, maybe it could explain the difference?

Comment: No, Moscow time is UTC+3, so 10:19 on 21 February in London was 13:19 in Moscow, and 14:29 in on 20 February in London was 17:29 in Moscow. https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converter.html?iso=20190221T101900&p1=136&p2=166

Comment: @BoarGules Thank you a lot for your help :)